# How to select all rows WHERE a string filed start with a specific string

Tags: c#, where-clause, sqlcommand

How can I do this: select all rows WHERE a string filed start with a specific string like this (it's a command for `SqlDataAdapter` select command string in C#):

```
 SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE user_id = asd*
```

*asd* means all user_id filed that start with `asd`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a LIKE statement such as:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE user_id LIKE 'asd%'
```

The % is a wild card, so that would work if you're looking for a string that starts with asd, otherwise, if you're just looking for asd anywhere in the string:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE user_id LIKE '%asd%'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE user_id LIKE 'asd%'
```